# What does git rebase use to determine common ancestor?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I know that I can use `git merge-base` to determine the common ancestor when performing a `git merge`, **but it looks like this is not true for** `git rebase`

Here is my setup before `rebase`:
`master branch`: `A--Y--(C)`
and `dev branch`: `A-----C--D`
(C) is the outcome of me rebasing A--C onto A--Y, **same content, but different commit message**

`git merge-base master dev` will return A, and if I do `git merge dev`, I will see both **(C) and C** in my history

`git rebase master`, outcome is:
A--Y--(C)--(D) where (D) is D after rebase

Does `git rebase` consider (C) as the common ancestor? (This feels pretty hard to do in code) I am guessing it still uses A, but when it is cherry picking C,D to append to the end of `master`, C ended up as a **no-op**?

Comment: "I am guessing it still uses A, but when it is cherry picking C,D to append to the end of `master`, C ended up as a **no-op** (`git diff == null`)?" That would be my intuition of what happens conceptually, too.

Answer (score 7):

Let's start with this: what `git rebase` does is to *copy some commits*.  In your case, it appears to copy commit `C` but not commit `D`.  (I think you are asking why, but are assuming that it has something to do with the merge base, and that is probably not correct.)

The set of commits that `git rebase` chooses to copy is largely, *but not entirely*, determined by the result of:

```
git rev-list <upstream>..HEAD
```

where `<upstream>` is the argument you pass to `git rebase`, or the configured upstream.  For instance, with `git rebase master`, the `<upstream>` in this sequence is `master`.  Your current branch is `dev`, so `HEAD` refers to `dev`.  So the set of commits to copy is that listed by:

```
git rev-list master..dev
```

(although there are additional options added; see below).

If I read your graph right, the input graph is:

```
...--A--Y   <-- master
      \
       C--D   <-- dev
```

so that the output of this `git rev-list` is commits `C` and `D`.

Rebase then goes on to:

1. `git checkout` the tip of the target branch (commit `Y` here);
2. run—sometimes literally, sometimes figuratively— `git cherry-pick` on commits `C` and `D`; and, finally
3. run `checkout -B dev HEAD` (not quite literally but the same effect: get back on `dev`, after moving `dev` to point to the final copied commit).

What I think you are asking about directly—which I think is not what you *should* be asking—is which commit is used as a merge base during cherry-picking.  The answer here is that the merge base of a cherry-pick is the parent commit of that cherry-pick.  So for the `git cherry-pick C` step, the merge base, if a merge is required, is commit `A`: `C`'s parent.  For the `git cherry-pick D` step, the merge base, if a merge is required, is commit `C`: `D`'s parent.

Now, I listed several "additional options" items above.  These refer to the commit selection process.  In particular, `git rebase` has two ways to toss commits *off* of its "to copy" list.  (It also generates the list in the reverse of the usual backwards order, so that it does the cherry-picking in the forwards order instead.)

The main way that it eliminates commits from the to-copy list is to use `git patch-id`.  The `git patch-id` command computes an ID number, which one hopes is "unique enough", based on the patch found by comparing a commit to its immediate parent, throwing away line numbers and some other items that might affect a cherry-picked commit.  The result should be the *same* ID if the commit was already cherry-picked, but *different* if not.

Hence, after listing `C` and `D`, Git goes on to compare their patch-IDs to the patch-ID of commit `Y`.

There are two commands that do this sort of thing, one meant for users, and the other being `git rev-list`.  The user-facing command is `git cherry`, but I think here, the computer-oriented `git rev-list` is actually much easier to explain.

The interesting thing here is how Git knows to compare all the patch IDs of commits `C` and `D` to the patch ID of commit `Y`, when the initial graph is the one we showed above.  Or, if the graph were:

```
...--A--E--F--G   <-- master
      \
       C--D   <-- dev
```

the two sets of patch-IDs to be compared would be those for (C, D) vs those for (E, F, G).  If we had:

```
          H--I
         /    \
...--A--G---J--K   <-- master
      \
       \   D
        \ / \
         C   F   <-- dev
          \ /
           E
```

the sets to compare would be (C, D, E, F) vs (G, H, I, J, K).  And this, I think, makes the whole concept much clearer: the way this works is that `git rev-list` can examine *both* branches down to the point where they meet, and collect a set of commits for each "side".

The way we get `git rev-list` to do this is:

```
git rev-list --left-right master...dev
```

(note the three dots here, and the order of `dev` and `master` matters only to determine which commits are "left side"—on `master` but not on `dev`—and which are "right side", on `dev` but not on `master`).

This three-dot notation, along with this `--left-right` idea, is how Git figures out which commits to put in which set, in order to compute the complete set of patch-IDs.  If the patch ID of a left side commit is the same as the patch ID of a right side commit, those commits, though they are different in some way, represent the same *change*: they are cherries that have already been cherry-picked.

The `git rebase` command skips over these pre-picked cherries.  It only cherry-picks the *remaining* commits, whichever those are.  The `git rebase` code runs `git rev-list --right-only --cherry-pick --no-merges <upstream>..HEAD` to get its list of commits to copy in step 2.  Then it runs those three steps.  If the patch ID of either `C` or `D` matches the patch ID for commit `Y`, *that commit is never copied at all*.  In this case, it would seem that commit `D`'s patch ID may match commit `Y`'s.

I also said that there are *two* ways that commits can be eliminated.  This cherry detection is one of them, and I suspect it's the reason you see the result I think you see.  The other is what Git calls `--fork-point`, which is a bit complicated.  I'm not going to cover it here.  It only omits "early" commits: that is, it finds a point along the `C--D` chain—this would make more sense if the chain were longer—that it thinks it should drop, and only copies commits *after* that point.  Since commit `C` gets copied, it cannot be the fork-point code causing commit `D` to get omitted.